# PowerCommands for Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, ide, powercommands

I see that [PowerCommands for Visual Studio 2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e5f41ad9-4edc-4912-bca3-91147db95b99) supports visual studio 2012, but it was last updated in Aug 2010. Is there a new "PowerCommands for Visual Studio 2012" or is there a viable replacement?

Comment: Installing this reminds me how much I miss discernible icons..(

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You don't need a replacement. If you install the Power Commands again, **from within VS 2012** (Tools -> Extensions and Updates), it will be applied to VS 2012.

From [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/terje/archive/2012/03/22/visual-studio-amp-tfs-11-ndash-list-of-extensions-and.aspx):

> > Just reinstall, even if you already have it for VS2010. The reinstall will then apply it to VS 11

I just did it, and it worked perfectly.

**Edit**

[Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd)

[Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2012 Update 1 Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f)

For Visual Studio 2013, it looks like Power Commands is now part of Power Productivity Tools.

Comment: Indeed, it does. I've had it on VS2012 for a little bit now.

Comment: The one I'm having a hard time finding is Productivity Power Tools. I like to align assignments, and I'm having a had time finding that for VS 2012.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using [VSCommands for Visual Studio 2012](http://bit.ly/PYmtXa). This tool provided all I needed from PowerCommands and more.

Answer (score 0):

Most of what was in the Productivity Power Tools are now part of VS 2012.  There are a few items missing, afaik, what are you looking for in particular ?

Comment: I'm looking for the feature of vertical tabs at the left side and the enhanced scrollbar.

Comment: what are the features that are now part of VS 2012? I like the feature that allow you to open a file (in the solution explorer) in the directory it resides. Also, the feature that allows you to collapse all nodes in the solution explorer. I found [VSCommands for Visual Studio 2012](http://bit.ly/PYmtXa) that gave me the same and more.

Comment: @FrancoisNel Collapse all nodes is in 2012 I believe

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on the [Productivity Power Tools 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd) page, the Power Commands were added to that addon.

Answer (score 0):

Download the VS2010/2012 version from the [VS Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e5f41ad9-4edc-4912-bca3-91147db95b99).

Unzip the .vsix to a folder (i.e. using the great [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html)), it's just a zip file.

Edit the extension.vsixmanifest file and add this element after the 11.0 one:

```
  <VisualStudio Version="12.0">
    <Edition>Pro</Edition>
  </VisualStudio>
```

Repeat for every future version of VS that comes out ;)

Now re-zip the contents (files, not the root folder, so that the extension.vsixmanifest is at the root of the zip file, not within a folder), rename the zip file to .vsix, and double-click to install to all your newly supported editions.

Enjoy!