# VS2012 Sort Usings doesn't move System Usings first?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I set up a virtual machine specific for WP8 development with VS2012 PRO.

When I rightclick->Organize Usings->Sort Usings, every using is just sorted alphabetically.
I'm expecting the System usings to be first.

Did I miss some setting or why does my enviroment act like this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Directives Sorted in Wrong Order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715340/using-directives-sorted-in-wrong-order)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

It is a visual studio option: `Options, Text Editor, C#, Advanced, Place System directives first when sorting usings`